# EF Core - one to many: efficiency in searching for a subitem

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In a one-to-many relationship, something like this:

```
class Author { string id, ICollection<Book> Books }
class Book { string Id, Author AuthorRef, string AuthorRefId }
```

If I have an authorId + bookId, and I want to get the book object, what is more efficient?

1. Query the `Authors` DBset with `authorId`, and then search within the result's `Books` collection by `bookId`
2. Query on the `Books` collection like

   ```
   Books.Where(b => b.Id == bookId && b.AuthorRefId  == authorId)
   ```

I imagine there are benefits to querying the DB, but onoh more objects are searched overall...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the generated SQL for each query.

If you query `Authors` first, and assuming you do it all in one query and *only* project `Books`, then the resulting SQL will probably look something like

```sql
SELECT B.*
FROM Authors AS a
JOIN Books AS b ON b.AuthorRefId = a.Id
WHERE a.Id = @authorId
  AND b.Id = @bookId
```

Whereas if you query `Books` directly, it will probably look a bit simpler.

```sql
SELECT
  B.*
FROM Books AS b 
WHERE b.AuthorRefId = @authorId
  AND b.Id = @bookId;
```

The difference between these is not huge, if `Authors` is correctly indexed, as it's only a single-row lookup. But the second is obviously going to be a bit more efficient.

But if you first get the whole `Author` object and use a `.Include(a => a.Books)`, then you will probably end up with either two separate queries or a big join, depending whether you have SplitQueries configured.

```sql
SELECT
  A.*,
  B.*
FROM Authors AS a
JOIN Books AS b ON b.AuthorRefId = a.Id
WHERE a.Id = @authorId
  AND b.Id = @bookId
```

Essentially it depends on whether you actually need the `Author` object in the first place. If you don't, try to avoid pulling it back off the database at all.

---

Having said that, if you have a `bookId` it's a bit werd that you need to look up the `authorId` at all, given that you already have a unique identifier for the `Book`.